# How to inhibit vim from changing window size of invoking console?

Tags: vim

When I use vim, not gvim, but just vim in my console (GNOME, Cinnamon, etc.), it changes the width of the console to 80 columns from whatever it was. I can use

```
set lines=n columns=n
```

in .vimrc to impose a new size, but I want it to keep the size of the console in which I'm launching it.

Answer (score 2):

Check with `:verbose set lines? columns?` where this got set, and disable those calls. Then, Vim will stick with the original terminal size.

If `:verbose` doesn't yield the answer, capture a full log of the Vim startup with `vim -V20vimlog`, and search for those options.